# select subselect parse results oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-xml-db

Temp Extract :

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "TRANSACTION"."TEMP_EXTRACT" 
   (    
    "EXTRACT_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "APP_DATA_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "IT_DEBIT_BANKID" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "IT_DEBIT_ACCOUNT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "IT_CREDIT_BANKID" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "IT_CREDIT_ACCOUNT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "IT_INT_TRAN_ID" NUMBER(15,0), 
    "IT_HOST_TC" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), 
    "IT_BAI_TRAN_CODE" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IT_SWFT_TRAN_CODE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "IT_DESCR" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE), 
    "IT_CUST_REF_ID" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "IT_TOTAL_DEBIT" NUMBER(15,3), 
    "IT_TOTAL_CREDIT" NUMBER(15,3), 
    "IT_SERIAL_NUM" NUMBER(11,0), 
    "IT_DR_CR_CODE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "IT_PRESENT_DESC" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE), 
    "IT_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "IT_LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "IT_PRINT_OR_ELECT" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "IT_AVAIL_BAL" NUMBER(15,3), 
    "OR_POST_DATE" DATE, 
    "OR_TRAN_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "AD_ENTRY_DATE" DATE, 
    "AD_VALUE_DATE" DATE, 
    "ST_STAGE" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "REF_BEN_REF" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "REF_USR_REF" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "REF_MID_REF" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "REF_BATCH_NUM" VARCHAR2(7 BYTE), 
    "REF_SEQ_NUM" VARCHAR2(7 BYTE), 
    "REF_HOST_BLK_NUM" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "REF_HOST_BAL_SEQ_NUM" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "ACH_SENDER_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_SENDER_IDTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RECEIVER_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RECEIVER_IDTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_PAYINFO_SEQ" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_EXCH_RATE" NUMBER(38,3), 
    "ACH_EXCH_RATECODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_PAYOR_BNKIDTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_PAYOR_BNKID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_BEN_BNKIDTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_BEN_BNKID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_BEN_ACCTID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ACT_WTHNBNKIDTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ACT_WTHNBNKID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_INSTR_CODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_INSTR_ADDINFO" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REMITINFO_1" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REMITINFO_2" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REMITINFO_3" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REMITINFO_4" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REG_REP1" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REG_REP2" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_REG_REP3" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "ACH_LAST_UPDATETIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "ACH_CRE_DT_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ACH_X12_INT_CTRLNUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_X12_GRP_CTRLNUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_X12_TRAN_CTRLNUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_PMT_RCPTDTTIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ACH_PMT_FORMATCODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_BIZ_FXCODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_CRDR_FLAG" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_BEN_ACCTTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_TRACE_SEQID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ENTRY_DATE" DATE, 
    "ACH_PAYMENT_DATE" DATE, 
    "ACH_ACH_COMPANYID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_CHANNEL" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_TRAN_CODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_INDIV_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RDFI_NUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RDFI_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RDFIBRNCH_CNTRY" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RECID_NUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_RMTADVHNDL_CODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_FILE_CTRL_NUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_PMT_COUNT" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_PMT_HASH_TOT" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ACH_COMPANYNAME" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_CLOB_820" CLOB, 
    "ACH_SOURCE_INFO" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_CUST_REF" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_BEN_PARTY_IDENTIFIER" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_CLOB2_820" CLOB, 
    "ACH_IAT_CODE1" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_IAT_CODE2" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_FOR_CORR" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_FOR_CORR_NUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_FOR_CORR_ID_QUAL" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_FOR_CORR_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_FOR_CORR_CD" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ACH_ACH_FILE_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_PAYOR_ACCT_ID" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_PAYOR_BNK_ID_TYPE" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_BEN_ACCT_ID" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_BEN_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_SENDER_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_SENDING_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_ACCT_WITHINS_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_ACCT_WITHINS_BNK_ID_TYPE" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID_TYPE" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_SENDER_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_RECVR_BNK_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_OMAD" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_IMAD" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_OB1" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_OB2" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_OB3" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_OB4" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_GRP_BTCHID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_GRP_NBOFTXS" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_GRP_CTRL_SUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_PMT_INFID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_PMT_NBOFTXS" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_PMT_CTRL_SUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_CRE_DT_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_SEG_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_SEG_FRB_APPL_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "WIRES_X12_INT_CTRLNUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_X12_GRP_CTRLNUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_X12_TRAN_CTRLNUM" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_SOURCE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_TEMPLATE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_PMT_METH_MOP" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_PMT_MSG_TYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_PMT_MSG_SUBTYPE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_DIRECTION" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "WIRES_WIRE_BBI" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE) 
    )
    ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS ;
```

ACH_ADDENDA :

```
CREATE TABLE "TRANSACTION"."ACH_ADDENDA" 
   (    "ACH_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RMR_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "RMR_CODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "INVOICE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "RMR_PAID_AMT" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "RMR_ORIG_AMT" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "RMR_DISC_AMT" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "RMR_DATE" DATE, 
    "REF_CODE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "REF_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "REF_NAME" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "REF_INSTRUCTIONS" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ADX_INSTRUCTIONS" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ENT_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA01" ;

    SELECT DISTINCT
                  XMLELEMENT (
                       "ACCOUNT",
                       XMLAGG (
                          XMLELEMENT (
                             "ACCOUNT_INFO",
                             XMLELEMENT("BANK_ID",account_summary.bank_id),
                             XMLELEMENT("ACCOUNT_NUMBER",account_summary.account_number),
XMLFOREST("BNK_ID_TYPE",ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.BNK_ID_TYPE),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.CURR_BAL*100 AS "CURR_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.COLL_BAL*100 AS "COLL_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.AVG_COLL_BAL*100 AS "AVG_COLL_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.AVAIL_BAL*100 AS "AVAIL_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.ONE_DAY_FLOAT*100 AS "ONE_DAY_FLOAT"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.TWO_DAY_FLOAT*100 AS "TWO_DAY_FLOAT"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.THREE_DAY_FLOAT*100 AS "THREE_DAY_FLOAT"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.AVG_CURR_BAL*100 AS "AVG_CURR_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.INTEREST_CURR_BAL*100 AS "INTEREST_CURR_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.PRCPL_BAL*100 AS "PRCPL_BAL"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.BEG_LED*100 AS "BEG_LED"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.LOAN_AVAIL_BAL*100 AS "LOAN_AVAIL_BAL"),  
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.NUM_CREDITS AS "NUM_CREDITS"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.NUM_DEBITS AS "NUM_DEBITS"),
xmlforest(account_summary.amt_credits*100 as "AMT_CREDITS"),
XMLFOREST(ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.AMT_DEBITS*100 AS "AMT_DEBITS"),
     XMLELEMENT (
      "TRANSACTIONS",

    (SELECT DISTINCT XMLAGG (

               XMLELEMENT (
                  "TRANSACTION",

                  XMLFOREST (


TE.it_INT_TRAN_ID,
            TE.IT_HOST_TC,
            TE.IT_BAI_TRAN_CODE,
            TE.IT_SWFT_TRAN_CODE,
            TE.IT_SERIAL_NUM,
            TE.IT_DESCR AS "TRANS_DESC",
            TE.IT_CUST_REF_ID,
            TE.IT_TOTAL_DEBIT*100 AS "TOTAL_DEBIT",
            TE.IT_TOTAL_CREDIT*100 AS "TOTAL_CREDIT",
            TE.IT_DR_CR_CODE,
            TE.IT_PRINT_OR_ELECT,
            TE.IT_AVAIL_BAL AS "AVAIL_BAL",
            TE.OR_POST_DATE,
            TE.OR_TRAN_DATE,
            TE.AD_ENTRY_DATE,
            TE.AD_VALUE_DATE,
            TE.ST_STAGE,
            TE.REF_BEN_REF,
            TE.REF_USR_REF,
            TE.REF_MID_REF,
            TE.REF_BATCH_NUM,
            TE.REF_SEQ_NUM,
            TE.REF_HOST_BLK_NUM,
            TE.REF_HOST_BAL_SEQ_NUM,
                TE.ACH_ID,
                                TE.ACH_SENDER_ID,
                                TE.ACH_SENDER_IDTYPE,
                                TE.ACH_RECEIVER_ID,
                                TE.ACH_RECEIVER_IDTYPE,
                                TE.ACH_PAYINFO_SEQ,
                                TE.ACH_EXCH_RATE,
                                TE.ACH_EXCH_RATECODE,
                                TE.ACH_PAYOR_BNKIDTYPE,
                                TE.ACH_PAYOR_BNKID,
                                TE.ACH_BEN_BNKIDTYPE,
                                TE.ACH_BEN_BNKID,
                                TE.ACH_BEN_ACCTID,
                                TE.ACH_ACT_WTHNBNKIDTYPE,
                                TE.ACH_ACT_WTHNBNKID,
                                TE.ACH_INSTR_CODE,
                                TE.ACH_INSTR_ADDINFO,
                                TE.ACH_REMITINFO_1,
                                TE.ACH_REMITINFO_2,
                                TE.ACH_REMITINFO_3,
                                TE.ACH_REMITINFO_4,
                                TE.ACH_REG_REP1,
                                TE.ACH_REG_REP2,
                                TE.ACH_REG_REP3,
                                TE.ACH_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP,
                                TE.ACH_LAST_UPDATETIMESTAMP,
                                TE.ACH_CRE_DT_TIME,
                                TE.ACH_X12_INT_CTRLNUM,
                                TE.ACH_X12_GRP_CTRLNUM,
                                TE.ACH_X12_TRAN_CTRLNUM,
                                TE.ACH_PMT_RCPTDTTIME,
                                TE.ACH_PMT_FORMATCODE,
                                TE.ACH_BIZ_FXCODE,
                                TE.ACH_CRDR_FLAG,
                                TE.ACH_BEN_ACCTTYPE,
                                TE.ACH_TRACE_SEQID,
                                TE.ACH_ENTRY_DATE,
                                TE.ACH_PAYMENT_DATE,
                                TE.ACH_ACH_COMPANYID,
                                TE.ACH_CHANNEL,
                                TE.ACH_TRAN_CODE,
                                TE.ACH_INDIV_ID,
                                TE.ACH_RDFI_NUM,
                                TE.ACH_RDFI_ID,
                                TE.ACH_RDFIBRNCH_CNTRY,
                                TE.ACH_RECID_NUM,
                                TE.ACH_RMTADVHNDL_CODE,
                                TE.ACH_FILE_CTRL_NUM,
                                TE.ACH_PMT_COUNT,
                                TE.ACH_PMT_HASH_TOT,
                                TE.ACH_ACH_COMPANYNAME,
                                TE.ACH_CLOB_820,
                                TE.ACH_SOURCE_INFO,
                                TE.ACH_CUST_REF,
                                TE.ACH_BEN_PARTY_IDENTIFIER,
                                TE.ACH_CLOB2_820,
                                TE.ACH_IAT_CODE1,
                                TE.ACH_IAT_CODE2,
                                TE.ACH_FOR_CORR,
                                TE.ACH_FOR_CORR_NUM,
                                TE.ACH_FOR_CORR_ID_QUAL,
                                TE.ACH_FOR_CORR_ID,
                                TE.ACH_FOR_CORR_CD,
                                TE.ACH_ACH_FILE_ID,

                   TE.WIRES_PAYOR_ACCT_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_PAYOR_BNK_ID_TYPE,
                   TE.WIRES_BEN_ACCT_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_BEN_BNK_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_SENDER_BNK_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_sending_bnk_id,
                   TE.WIRES_ACCT_WITHINS_BNK_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_ACCT_WITHINS_BNK_ID_TYPE,
                   TE.WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID_TYPE,
                   TE.WIRES_wire_sender_bnk_id,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_RECVR_BNK_ID,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_OMAD,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_IMAD,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_OB1,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_OB2,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_OB3,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_OB4,
                   TE.WIRES_GRP_BTCHID,
                   TE.WIRES_GRP_NBOFTXS,
                   TE.WIRES_GRP_CTRL_SUM,
                   TE.WIRES_PMT_INFID,
                   TE.WIRES_PMT_NBOFTXS,
                   TE.WIRES_PMT_CTRL_SUM,
                   TE.WIRES_CRE_DT_TIME,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_SEG_TIME,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_SEG_FRB_APPL_TIME,
                   TE.WIRES_X12_INT_CTRLNUM,
                   TE.WIRES_X12_GRP_CTRLNUM,
                   TE.WIRES_X12_TRAN_CTRLNUM,
                   TE.WIRES_SOURCE,
                   TE.WIRES_TEMPLATE,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_PMT_METH_MOP,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_PMT_MSG_TYPE,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_PMT_MSG_SUBTYPE,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_DIRECTION,
                   TE.WIRES_WIRE_BBI

                                            ) as "TRANS",
                                                     XMLFOREST ( 
                                                          (SELECT 
                                                          XMLAGG (
                                                            XMLELEMENT("PMTREL",
                                                               XMLFOREST(ACH_ADDENDA.RMR_CODE as "RMR_CODE",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.INVOICE_NUMBER as "INVOICE_NUMBER",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.RMR_PAID_AMT as "RMR_PAID_AMT",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.RMR_ORIG_AMT as "RMR_ORIG_AMT",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.RMR_DISC_AMT as "RMR_DISC_AMT",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.RMR_DATE as "RMR_DATE",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.REF_CODE as "REF_CODE",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.REF_ID as "REF_ID",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.REF_NAME as "REF_NAME",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.REF_INSTRUCTIONS as "REF_INSTRUCTIONS",
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.ADX_INSTRUCTIONS as "ADX_INSTRUCTIONS" ,
                                                                          ACH_ADDENDA.ENT_NUMBER as "ENT_NUMBER"
                                                                     ) AS "PMTREL1"
                                                                     )
                                                                     )
                                                                     FROM temp_extract TE, ach_addenda
                                                                     WHERE TE.APP_DATA_ID = ach_addenda.ach_id
                                                                     AND TE.EXTRACT_ID = EXTRACT_ID

                                                                     AND TE.ST_STAGE  IN ('Payment Rejected', 'CLABE Payment Rejected', 'Payment Accepted', 'ACHPayment_Confirmed') 




                                                                     )AS "PMTRELINFO"
                                                                      ),

                                              XMLForest(
                                                              (SELECT  
                                                                  XMLAgg(
                                                                     XMLELEMENT("ADDRESS",
                                                                                XMLFOREST(ad.descr as "DESCR",
                                                                                ad.name as "NAME",
                                                                                ad.ADDRESS1 AS "ADDRESS1",
                                                                                ad.ADDRESS2 AS "ADDRESS2",
                                                                                ad.ADDRESS3 AS "ADDRESS3",
                                                                                ad.CITY AS "CITY",
                                                                                ad.STATE AS "STATE",
                                                                                ad.COUNTRY AS "COUNTRY",
                                                                                ad.MAILCODE AS "MAILCODE"

                                                                                          ) as "ADDR1" 
                                                                                )
                                                                         )
                                                                FROM temp_extract te, address ad
                                                                WHERE te.EXTRACT_ID  = EXTRACT_ID
                                                                AND (
                                                                      (TE.APP_DATA_ID = AD.WIRE_ID AND (ad.descr='Payor Address' 
                                                                                                    or ad.descr='Beneficiary Address' 
                                                                                                    OR ad.descr='Account With Institution Address' 
                                                                                                    or ad.descr='Intermediary Institution Address'
                                                                                                    or ad.descr='Wire Beneficiary Bank Address'
                                                                                                    OR ad.descr='Wire Sender Bank Address'
                                                                                                    or ad.descr='Account Servicing Institution'))
                                                                OR    (TE.APP_DATA_ID = AD.ACH_ID AND      (ad.descr='Payor Address' 
                                                                                                            or ad.descr='Beneficiary Address' 
                                                                                                            or ad.descr='Account With Institution Address'))
                                                                     )



                                        ) AS "ADDRESS_INFO" 
                                                             ), 
                                                            XMLForest(
                                                              (SELECT 
                                                                  XMLAgg(
                                                                     XMLELEMENT("AMOUNT",
                                                                                XMLFOREST(additional_amount.description as "DESCR",
                                                                                ADDITIONAL_AMOUNT.AMOUNT*100 AS "AMOUNT",
                                                                                additional_amount.CURRENCY as "CURRENCY"
                                                                                          ) as "AMT1" 
                                                                                )
                                                                         )

                                                                 FROM additional_amount, TEMP_EXTRACT TE 
                                                                 where te.it_int_tran_id=additional_amount.int_tran_id


                                                               ) AS "AMOUNT_INFO" 
                                                             )

                         ) 
                         )

                         FROM  TEMP_EXTRACT TE
                         WHERE TE.EXTRACT_ID = EXTRACT_ID

                         )                 )))).getClobVal ()

              INTO  v_xml
              FROM  account_summary
              WHERE account_summary.account_number = p_acct_num
              AND   ACCOUNT_SUMMARY.BANK_ID = P_BANK_ID
              AND   to_char(POST_DATE) = to_char(r_max_all_sameday);
```

-- this needs to be local to just the values in temp table from table A (transaction type 1) but on the xml it is showing up in the output for transaction type 2 as well. How would i go about making that sub select local with the where query in it? Thanks for your time.

The output is as below:

```
<ACCOUNT>
<ACCOUNT_INFO>
 <BANK_ID>21</BANK_ID>
 <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>2533167775</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
<TRANSACTIONS>
<TRANSACTION>
 <IT_INT_TRAN_ID>450814</IT_INT_TRAN_ID>
 <IT_CUST_REF_ID>1234600</IT_CUST_REF_ID>
 <IT_DR_CR_CODE>D</IT_DR_CR_CODE>
 <OR_POST_DATE>0017-03-15</OR_POST_DATE>
 <AD_ENTRY_DATE>0023-06-15</AD_ENTRY_DATE>
 <AD_VALUE_DATE>0017-03-15</AD_VALUE_DATE>
 <ST_STAGE>Payment Accepted</ST_STAGE>
 <ACH_SENDER_ID>ACHtestFTPS </ACH_SENDER_ID>
 <ACH_SENDER_IDTYPE>Unknown</ACH_SENDER_IDTYPE>
 <ACH_RECEIVER_ID>bbvacompass </ACH_RECEIVER_ID>
 <ACH_RECEIVER_IDTYPE>Unknown</ACH_RECEIVER_IDTYPE>
 <PMTRELINFO>
<PMTRELINFO>
 <RMR_CODE>IV</RMR_CODE>
 <INVOICE_NUMBER>5940009404</INVOICE_NUMBER>
 <RMR_PAID_AMT>200.0</RMR_PAID_AMT>
 <RMR_ORIG_AMT>0.0</RMR_ORIG_AMT>
 <RMR_DISC_AMT>0.0</RMR_DISC_AMT>
 <RMR_DATE>2015-06-23</RMR_DATE>
 <REF_CODE>PO</REF_CODE>
 <REF_ID>005001234501</REF_ID>
 <REF_NAME>3</REF_NAME>
 </PMTRELINFO>
 </TRANSACTION>
 <TRANSACTION>
 <IT_INT_TRAN_ID>2837</IT_INT_TRAN_ID>
 <OR_POST_DATE>2013-09-09</OR_POST_DATE>
 <AD_VALUE_DATE>2013-09-06</AD_VALUE_DATE>
 <ST_STAGE>HIFV4</ST_STAGE>
 <REF_MID_REF>130906100719F101</REF_MID_REF>
 <WIRES_PAYOR_ACCT_ID>875212 </WIRES_PAYOR_ACCT_ID>
 <WIRES_BEN_BNK_ID>270021163 </WIRES_BEN_BNK_ID>
 <WIRES_SENDER_BNK_ID>021000089 </WIRES_SENDER_BNK_ID>
 <WIRES_ACCT_WITHINS_BNK_ID_TYPE>Other</WIRES_ACCT_WITHINS_BNK_ID_TYPE>
 <WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID>CITIUS33XXX </WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID>
 <WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID_TYPE>Other</WIRES_ACCT_SER_BNK_ID_TYPE>
 <PMTRELINFO>
**<PMTRELINFO>
 <RMR_CODE>IV</RMR_CODE>
 <INVOICE_NUMBER>5940009404</INVOICE_NUMBER>
 <RMR_PAID_AMT>200.0</RMR_PAID_AMT>
 <RMR_ORIG_AMT>0.0</RMR_ORIG_AMT>
 <RMR_DISC_AMT>0.0</RMR_DISC_AMT>
 <RMR_DATE>2015-06-23</RMR_DATE>
 <REF_CODE>PO</REF_CODE>
 <REF_ID>005001234501</REF_ID>
 <REF_NAME>3</REF_NAME>
 </PMTRELINFO>**
 </TRANSACTION>
 </TRANSACTIONS>
 </ACCOUNT_INFO>
 </ACCOUNT>
```

The PMTRELINFO is applicable to the first transaction, not the second.

Comment: Can you explain the result you are trying to achieve?  Also please include the full SQL, the snippets you have pasted don't seem to be cohesive as well as any table definitions.

Comment: Which column(s) in ach_addenda link to a specific transaction in temp_extract? It is kind of hard to follow what's going on with partial code and no raw data. Can you create a simplified but complete version that demonstrates the issue you're having? (Perhaps as an SQL Fiddle)

Comment: All the columns in ach_addenda link ONLY to transaction 1 in the temp extract table. Transaction type 2 has no such addenda records. The where clause in the xmlelement "pmtrelinfo" specifies the stage from a base table that only applies to transaction type 1. 1 transaction of type transaction type 1 can have more than 1 addenda record so i did not insert into the temp table and instead am doing a join for the ach_addenda table and temp table.

Comment: The row in ach_addenda is related only to transaction 1, but how is that known - what is the join condition? If you look at the row how do you know which transaction it belongs to? You also talk about *type* 1 and 2 which is confusing. Only type 1 transactions have ach_addenda records, but you still need to know how to link each type 1 transaction to *its* specific addenda(s).

Comment: The join condition should be based on that where clause where the stage from the temp table associates it only to ACH (which would be transaction 1 type). So the temp_extract is getting joined to the ACH_ADDENDA table.

Comment: @Roshan - as Nick and Alex have said, it's not clear why your results are incorrect. Please post some example rows for `temp_extract` and `ach_addenda`. Also I'm not able to turn the posted code into valid SQL. Please update this so the whole statement is shown in a single code block.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PMTRELINFO element, the only criteria that is linking the two tables is:

```
           WHERE TE.APP_DATA_ID = ach_addenda.ach_id
           AND TE.EXTRACT_ID = EXTRACT_ID
```

So

1. there does not appear to be anything is limiting transaction types
   to 1, or 2 or anything else, and/or
2. the second predicate, in the absence of a table alias, might be not working as you anticipate

But I agree with the others - the example is very hard to follow as to what it is you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Connor, The App_data_id is unique to transaction 1 and transaction 2. So the ach_addenda_id would only equate to being equal to app_data_id for transaction type 1. The extract_id is to signify that all these transaction(s) would fall under <<transactions>> as separate <transaction>.

Comment: Plus the TE.ST_STAGE clause is only equivalent to Tran type 1.